# Cmake searching for wrong files?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to compile a tool which a teacher of mine gave me. It uses the Boost libraries (which I have set up and set the environment variables) and Boost is found by Cmake.

However, Cmake tells me it could not find the library named "boost_program_options". The output of cmake tells me that it is only looking for files with names "libboost_program_options-**vc110**-mt-1_61". In my Boost directory I'm only able to find files named "libboost_program_options-**vc140**-mt-1_61" which are all contained in D:\local\boost_1_61_0\lib64-msvc-14.0 (which I set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to). BOOST_ROOT ist set to D:\local\boost_1_61_0 and BOOST_INCLUDEDIR is set to D:\local\boost_1_61_0\boost. So, why is Cmake looking for the wrong files?

The Cmake file I was given is

```
project(generator)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(BOOST_MIN_VERSION "1.55.0")
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lboost_program_options")

if(UNIX)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=gnu++0x")
endif()
```

Answer (score 1):

**In short:**

Project for *Visual Studio 11* should use Boost libraries with suffix `-vc110`. With libraries `-vc140` *Visual Studio 14* should be used instead. Version of MSVC is choosen by [cmake-generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

**Explanations:**

It is [FindBoost.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake) script which search specific libraries. (You call this script via `find_package(Boost)`).

Boost uses libraries sufficies for differentiate libraries for different targets. Sufficies like `-vc110` denotes compiler using which libraries has been compiled. `-vc110` corresponds to `Visual Studio 11`, `-vc140` - to `Visual Studio 14`.

In you case *cmake-generator* [Visual Studio 11](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/generator/Visual%20Studio%2011%202012.html) is used (probably, it is default generator for your cmake installation). So Boost libraries should be compatible with its compiler. That is why only the libraries with `-vc110` suffix are searched: other libraries cannot be linked with this compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful clarification, but I'm still not sure how to fix my problem. Shall I use another Boost installation? Or can I somehow tell Cmake to search for -vc140 files?

Comment: You should use Boost installation which fits to the version of Visual Studio **you have**. If you have several Visual Studio installed, then you need to tell cmake which installation you want to use. This is achived by specifing corresponded [cmake-generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) with `-G` option in `cmake` invocation.